# How do a run EFS decrypt on a directory?

Tags: efs

In that directory, there's a mix of EFS-encrypted files, and just normal files.  Is there a simple way to decrypt everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ciphere.exe /d /s *.*
```

The /d is to decrypt.
The /s is to do that directory and subdirectories.

Comment: typo in the file name. it's "cipher.exe", not "ciphere.exe" (sorry I have no editing privileges)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method I can think of - Go to Explorer, customize the fields to show an encryption flag then simply sort by this and highlight the encrypted files, then right click to properties and unencrypt them.